# Selecting Distinct entries using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a tough time with a unique situation.  We need to return a unique dataset with all three columns so the result has a unique Company and Item but any of the keys.

We are using LINQ and I have a dataset with the following columns.

```
Company     Item    Key
------------------------------------------------------------
CompanyA    ItemA   9f94413b-63cb-4ad5-869a-4502988a22c9
CompanyA    ItemA   6c6a1b37-84a5-4878-a493-5dad5bf60ee4
CompanyB    ItemA   25c5ffca-69a5-45a6-9643-635791dc1bfd
```

The result I'm hoping for looks like this without care as to which key I get.

```
Company     Item    Key
CompanyA    ItemA   9f94413b-63cb-4ad5-869a-4502988a22c9
CompanyB    ItemA   25c5ffca-69a5-45a6-9643-635791dc1bfd
```

I've tried every combination of LINQ examples that I could find without success.  Is this a case where I first need to get a distinct list of Company/Item then loop again to get a Top(1) for the key on each of the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like this:

```cs
public class MyRecord
{
    public string Company {get;set;}
    public string Item {get;set;}
    public string Key {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can query it using `.GroupBy` by grouping on `Company` and `Item`. Next you can use `.Select` to build a new `MyRecord` with the grouped Company and Item values and the first Key from the group:

```cs
List<MyRecord> records = new List<MyRecord>()
{
    new MyRecord() { Company = "CompanyA", Item = "ItemA", Key = "9f94413b-63cb-4ad5-869a-4502988a22c9" },
    new MyRecord() { Company = "CompanyA", Item = "ItemA", Key = "6c6a1b37-84a5-4878-a493-5dad5bf60ee4" },
    new MyRecord() { Company = "CompanyB", Item = "ItemA", Key = "25c5ffca-69a5-45a6-9643-635791dc1bfd" }
};

List<MyRecord> results = records
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.Company, r.Item })
    .Select(g => new MyRecord() { Company = g.Key.Company, Item = g.Key.Item, Key = g.First().Key })
    .ToList();
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CRAGHH29112)

Comment: Thank you for answering my post and actually reading it.  Someone marked the post as a duplicate associated with another post which was not the same question/solution.  Your answer is very helpful!